# Java daemon execute commands

Tags: java

I have Java daemon which I want to pass shell commands. For example:

```
daemon load configuration.xml
```

Is this possible to do this?

Comment: Can you add some more details? I didn't get what you want to do ...

Comment: I think he means he wants to pass command line arguments to the program while the java daemon program is running, but yes I agree more details.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. There are tons of ways.

You can, for example, create a web service in your daemon and a simple app that would call different methods on that web service.

You could create a custom protocol and contact the daemon using it.

You could use JMS to pass some messages to the daemon.

You could use a database table as a task scheduling tool.

You could also simply write commands to a file for the daemon to read.

You could use OS-specific notification, like signals under linux

But if you are looking for an already-existing solution available in standard java libraries - then the answer is probably "no". You have to do some coding. JMS would seem the fastest way, unless you use some WS code generators.